# Cannot retrieve Users data from database. Server doesnt respond

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, backend

I am learning a MERN stack course on Udemy and currently I am trying to retrieve the user's data from the server but I can't. I am able to retrieve the post data but the connections times out for users data. Can you guys help me find out what went wrong? Thank you in advance!

`userController` snippet:

```
exports.allUsers = (req, res) => {
    const users = User.find({})
         .then((users) => {
              console.log(users);
         })
         .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

User routes snippet

```
 const express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router(),
  {userById, allUsers } = require('../controllers/userController');

  router.get('/users', allUsers);

  router.param('userID', userById)
  module.exports = router;
```

app.js code snippet

```
const express = require('express'),
  app = express(),
  postRoutes = require('./routes/post'),
  authRoutes = require('./routes/auth'),
  morgan = require("morgan"),
  mongoose = require("mongoose"),
  bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
  cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
  userRoutes = require('./routes/user'),
  expressValidator = require('express-validator');
  require('dotenv').config();

  mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI,
  { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true })
  .then(() => console.log("DB connected"));

  app.use(morgan("dev"));
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(cookieParser());
  app.use(expressValidator());
  app.use('/', postRoutes);
  app.use('/', authRoutes);
  app.use('/', userRoutes);
  app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  if (err.name === 'UnauthorizedError') {
     res.status(401).json({error: "Unauthorised"});
     }
  });

  app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
     console.log(`SERVER AT PORT: 3000`);
  });
```

Postman gets stuck here:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to end the request / respond to the request . In your `userController` you are missing ending/responding the request. You are just logging the user result .

Try this :

```js
exports.allUsers = (req, res) => {

 const users = User.find({})
 .then((users) => {
    console.log(users);
    res.status(200).json(users);
 })
 .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json(err.message);
 });

}
```